# ssh server C library?

Tags: c, ssh

I am looking for a C library that implements the server end of ssh. In particular, I am only interested in the subset that provides port forwarding. The ones that I have found so far (libssh2, NetSieben etc) seem to implement just the client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [libssh library](http://www.libssh.org/) supports client and server side.

Take a look at the 
[libssh server API documentation](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__server.html) and they also have some examples.

Comment: The last time I looked at libssh, it was a client-only implementation.  Server support must be a recent development.  Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: OTOH, it is entirely possible that I never came across libssh and got it confused with libssh2.

Comment: libssh has server support since a long time. I has been heavily improved the last 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org)'s source code.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH at http://www.openssh.com/ seems to include sshd, which is the server component. Caveat - I haven't used it myself.